# Rest WCF Post Json body parameter is always null while using Fiddler

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, post, fiddler

I have been struggling with this the past few days. I have researched the issue and tried the solutions posted. However it has not worked. I have REST WCF Post method that has

```
     [OperationContract(Name = "ImportRawJson")]
    WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "ImportRawJson/username/{username}/password/{password}/fileName/{fileName}")]
    string ImportRawJson(string username, string password, string fileName, string jsonStream);
```

I am able to consume this through web client. However when I try calling through Fiddler like below the body parameter always results in null and I get an exception.

Fiddler :
Post http://`localhost`/TimesheetService/Timesheet.svc/ImportRawJson/username/user/password/pwd/fileName/testfiddler

Request Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Request Body:
{ "jsonStream":{ "ImportRaw": {"TestXml": {"xml": "test" } }}}

Error:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 127
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wh4qxcu1x0vmiv45mmzuuaup; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 07 May 2013 14:00:58 GMT

{"ErrorCode":"Error","Message":"Procedure or function expects parameter 'jsonStream', which was not supplied."}

Any help as to how I can pass the body parameter. I truly appreciate. I am stuck at this point. Please help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Step 1: Use Fiddler to capture the request from the WebClient. Step 2: Use Fiddler's Composer to send exactly the same request that the WebClient sent. Done.

Comment: @EricLaw: I did try the steps you have mentioned and I get Bad Request error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request mentioning the "The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://localhost:jsonStream. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'jsonStream' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'ImportRaw' from namespace ''.'. "

Comment: @EricLaw: Thank you for your resoponse. I feel the jsonstring that I am sending in the parameter is not right, what am I missing here? I have tried all the various manipulations with it. Please help me.

Comment: If you followed the steps I provided, you would have captured a working request in the proper format, which had been generated by the Web Client. You could then use that working request from the Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code. First, if by "JSON stream" you mean any JSON document, you won't be able to use the type `string` for your code. Instead, you'll need to take it as a `Stream` (which can basically accept any arbitrary input). If you take the input as a string, you should pass a JSON string to it. And since you set the body type to `WrappedRequest`, you need to wrap the JSON string in an object, with the *parameter name* being the member name, and the value you want to pass to your function the value. For example, to pass the string `hello world` to your operation, you'd need to pass this request body:

```
{"jsonStream":"hello world"}
```

But if I guessed correctly, and you want to take any arbitrary JSON, you need to go with the `Stream` parameter. The blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx has more information about how to implement it.

Comment: @Carlosfigueria: Thank you so much!! Yes, I would like to accept a JSON document. And the link as helped me tremendously. I have marked it answered. However I also have a need to accept a json string for yet another method call with similar signature. And using {"jsonStream":"hello world"}, I always run into the null values exception. Please help me.

Comment: Figured out what was the issue. Thank you for pointing in the right direction.